# How to get catcode of a name defined with \let (or with \def)?

Tags: catcodes

How do I get catcode of `\tmpA` and `\tmpB`?

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \let\tmpA=a
  \def\tmpB{b}
  \the\catcode`a % 11, FINE; BUT WHAT ABOUT \tmpA AND \tmpA?
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\edef\temp{\noexpand\the\noexpand\catcode\`\tmpB}
  \temp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your earlier question, `\meaning` is your friend here.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \let\tmpA=a
  \def\tmpB{b}

1  \the\catcode`a % 11, FINE; BUT WHAT ABOUT \tmpA AND \tmpA?

  \def\zzz#1 #2 #3\relax{#1 #2}
  \edef\zz{\expandafter\zzz\meaning\tmpA. . \relax}
   \let\tmpknownletter=z
  \edef\zzletter{\expandafter\zzz\meaning\tmpknownletter. . \relax}


2   \ifx\zz\zzletter 11\else 0\fi % could test for other cases

3  \the\catcode\expandafter`\tmpB

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @bp2017 `\ifx\zzCombined{` compares `\zzCombined` with `{`  which will always be false. I do suspect though that this series of questions are XY questions: you have never said what your top level aim is, in all the thousands of packages available, perhaps three or four need to dissect `\meaning`  no package should ever need to work  out which number is used for `\newcount` (the only reason to use `\newcount` is to hide that information) . If you are just asking abstractly to see how tex works, that's fine too, but maybe start with better documented areas (such as how  `\def` and `\ifx` work)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle hear, hear.